# Javascript Changing Text to an Image

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events, blogger

```
<div id="myLuckyPost">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showLucky(root){ 
        var feed = root.feed; 
        var entries = feed.entry || []; 
        var entry = feed.entry[0]; 
        for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; ++j){
            if (entry.link[j].rel == 'alternate'){
                window.location = entry.link[j].href;
            }
        }
    } 
    function fetchLuck(luck){ 
        script = document.createElement('script'); 
        script.src = '/feeds/posts/summary?start-index='+luck+'&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLucky'; 
        script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
    } 
    function feelingLucky(root){ 
        var feed = root.feed; 
        var total = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10); 
        var luckyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*total);
        luckyNumber++; 
        a = document.createElement('a'); 
        a.href = '#random'; 
        a.rel = luckyNumber; 
        a.onclick = function(){
            fetchLuck(this.rel);
        }; 
        a.innerHTML = 'View Random Post';
        document.getElementById('myLuckyPost').appendChild(a); 
    } 
</script> 
<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=feelingLucky"></script>
```

This generates a link for random blogger post. Now I want to change the "View Random Post" ( `a.innerHTML = 'View Random Post';`) text link into an image. Is it possible?

Comment: Please format your code properly so that other people can read and understand it: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You want to *generate an image* from that string, or you want to *replace the text with an image*?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to replace the textlink and make an image button

Comment: From where should the image button identify the image it's supposed to use?

Comment: I don't know how to explain but instead of this:
    <a href='randompost'>View Random Post</a>

I want it to be like this:
    <a href='randompost'><img src='button.gif'></a>
Thanks

Comment: Jim, there are ways to dynamically generate an image with Javascript (for instance, with `canvas` or `svg`), so it's important to understand your actual intentions, which appears you have an image file you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
a.innerHTML = "<img src='button.gif' />";
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much!! I tried that earlier but I used single quote( ' ) instead of double quote ( " ) that's why it didn't work. Thank you and to everyone who helped!

Comment: The double quotes are needed as the string contains single quotes. You could also do it the other way around `'<img src="button.gif" />'`